# display a div below a selected input field? No JQuery

Tags: javascript, html

how to display a div everytime a user focus on a input field. there is already a div and it is hidden. the position of the div will change depending on the position of the selected field and it will be display below

this is my code

```js
formFieldListWrapper.style.top = ((((formSelectedFieldInput.offsetTop > (formWrapper.offsetHeight/2))?((formSelectedFieldInput.offsetTop-(formWrapper.offsetHeight/2))-(formSelectedFieldInput.offsetHeight+formWrapper.offsetHeight*0.02)):(formSelectedFieldInput.offsetTop))/formWrapper.offsetHeight)*100) + "%";
formFieldListWrapper.style.left = ((formSelectedFieldInput.offsetLeft/formWrapper.offsetWidth)*100) + "%";
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate, What you have tried so far?

Comment: i already did something. and it is appearing whenever i focus in a input field but the problem is it is not appear properly below the selected field. i want it to be similar like this one [link](http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html)

Comment: Can you please provide a snapshot,

Comment: the link i given. i want my field to be similar like that. a dropdown appearing below a selected input field.

Comment: Why do you even need javascript for that? You could do that with CSS only: http://jsfiddle.net/qz57za86/

Answer (score 7):

Why use javascript? This could be chieved by using [CSS only](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8f2zeu/)

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <input type="text" />
    <div class="dropdown">
        <p>Testing</p>
        <p>Css ONLY</p>
        <p>Dropdown</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
}

input:focus + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

little bit misred the question, if You need to position `div` dynamically like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8f2zeu/1/), You cloud use:

HTML

```
<div class="holder">
    <input type="text" />

</div>
<div class="holder" style="margin-top: 30px;">
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div class="dropdown">
    <p>Testing</p>
    <p>Css ONLY</p>
    <p>Dropdown</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.holder {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}

input:focus + .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

Javascript to position dropdown div

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
        this.parentNode.appendChild(document.querySelector('.dropdown'));
    });
}
```

Comment: With this example you need to add a div to every input. The OP wants a div reused is my guess.

Comment: The only problem I can think of with this sweet solution is when the div runs of the screen. CSS can't solve that.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
 formSelectedFieldInput.addEventListener("focus", setDivToInput, false);

 function setDivToInput(e)
 {
      var inputElement = e.target; //e.target refers to the element that fired the event.
      formFieldListWrapper.style.top = inputElement.offsetTop + formFieldListWrapper.offsetHeight + "px";
      formFieldListWrapper.style.left= inputElement.offsetLeft + "px";
      formFieldListWrapper.style.display = "block";
 }
```

The first line adds a focus event to the input. This sets the div to the input based upon it's position on the page. This is very basic and doesn't behave well when the div runs of the screen. You need to add logic for that.

Now for multiple inputs in a form

```
var nodes = form.querySelectorAll("input"); //replace with your form element
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; ++i)
{ 
    nodes[i].addEventListener("focus", setDivToInput, false); 
}

 function setDivToInput(e)
 {
      var node = e.target;
      formFieldListWrapper.style.top = node.offsetTop + formFieldListWrapper.offsetHeight + "px";
      formFieldListWrapper.style.left= node.offsetLeft + "px";
      formFieldListWrapper.style.display = "block";

 }
```

This code sets the focus event to all inputs in the form.