# Trying to print a <div> when <input> is in focus using just HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to print a message when the input is in focus and keep the printed message when the user is typing in the input field. I can get the message to be printed but it disappears when I start to type in the input field. Also I have a cancel button which requires to be clicked twice (once to get the input to not be in focus and get the message to not be printed and the second click triggers the cancel) if I have the input field in focus initially. Is there a way to avoid this?

This is what my code looks like

```css
   .create + .field-primary-message {
    display: none;
    background-color: red;
}

.create:focus + .field-primary-message {
    font-size: 11px;
    background-color: gold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <input class="create">
    <div class="field-primary-message">hello</div>
    <button>submit</button>
</body>
```

I followed the idea from this post [display a div below a selected input field? No JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922345/display-a-div-below-a-selected-input-field-no-jquery)

This works on JSBin but it does not work on my app. Is there a better way of doing it through HTML and CSS? I don't believe there's another property that's overriding my changes but that's a possibility right?

Comment: it's working here so maybe you've some issue on the rest of your app that makes it not working

Comment: I second this, the text remains open whilst typing for me. There is also no cancel button included in your example.

Comment: My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qcva5cm0/14/) appears to be working... All I really did was copy and past in your code. Except div style. I was trying something... All it does is set the size though.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Gonna play Devil's advocate and say have you triple checked for syntax errors in the rest of your app? consider running everything through CSSlint, and checking to make sure your HTML sn't truncated and is valid.

Comment: @JoelBonetR I think so too but the class I use in the html (create and field-primary-message) are being used just once throughout the app and there's no other general css property for input or div. If it's truly failing on some issue somewhere else in the app then I need some more digging to do.

Comment: @Tyler I'm on Chrome version -- 65.0.3325.162

Comment: @pj100 I'm gonna run CSSlint and see if anything new comes up. Thanks.